# Why ninject gets different Db instances in nunit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, ninject, ninject-extensions

I write integration tests for ASP.NET MVC based application, and I try to resolve ninject registration issue.

So for my ASP.NET MVC registration I have

```
 kernel.Bind(typeof(ICustomDbContext), typeof(IUnitOfWork))
                .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<CustomDbContext>())
                .InRequestScope();
```

Just to clarify  CustomDbContext implements IUnitOfWork and ICustomDbContext.
With that registration i guarantee that i have one unique instance per request for CustomDbContext. That registration works properly in scope of ASP.NET.

The problem is when i write integration tests.

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
}


[Test]
public async Task Test()
{
    // Arrange
    var claaService = kernel.Get<IService>();

}
```

On set up step i load my composition root (which is in ASP.NET MVC project).

The problem is when i get IService (Implementation of IService.cs is Service.cs and that service has dependencies to IUnitOfWork.cs and IGenericRepository.cs.  IGenericRepository.cs has dependency to ICustomDbContext). 

At the end when i access IService i should have same instance of CustomDbContext (and as I said in works in scope of MVC). 

I have tried  to resolve it in child scope, but the result is the same (they still have different hash code):

```
using (var childKernel1 = new ChildKernel(kernel))
{
    childKernel1.Rebind(typeof(ICustomDbContext), typeof(IUnitOfWork))
    .ToMethod(ctx => ctx.Kernel.Get<CustomDbContext>())
    .InThreadScope();

    var claaService = childKernel1.Get<IClassService>();

}
```

My questions are:

- Why this is happening ?
- How can I resolve it (it works if i do not use ninject, but i want to find a way with Ninject, even if i have to add additional configuration in integration tests) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Why this is happening ?

Ninject's scoping is limited to the lifetime of the container. You have setup the container to be created *for each [Test]* because you are using [`[SetUp]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-Attribute).

> This attribute is used inside a TestFixture to provide a common set of functions that are performed **just before each test method** is called.

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
}
```

If you want to use the same container across multiple tests in the same `[TestFixture]` (assuming this because you said "instance is not the same", but you didn't mention same as what), you need to use [`[OneTimeSetup]`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/OneTimeSetUp-Attribute) instead.

> This attribute is to identify methods that are called once **prior to executing any of the tests** in a fixture.

```
[OneTimeSetUp]
public void OneTimeSetUp()
{
    kernel = NinjectConfig.CreateKernel();
}
```

This of course assumes all of your relevant integration tests are in a single class.

In short, your Ninject container is being re-initialized on every test, which means all instances it manages are also being re-initialized.

Comment: In each test ICustomDbContext.cs and IUnitOfWork.cs should point to the same instance of CustomDbContext.cs. and yes you are right I re-initialized on every test (which is not right and i will move it in OneTimeSetUp) but the problem is different

Comment: So each test in question needs to be part of the same `[TestFixture]` in order for that to work. AFAIK, NUnit has no concept of "the entire application" like MVC does, which is where you normally put a [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/).

Comment: They are in the same file. To be honest i configure it somehow before 2 days, but i discard those changes and i can not remember how i did it. I remembered that i used ChildKernel and the registration was similar to the above one.